# IllegalArguementException - State Arguement : 5 on BottomSheet

Tags: android, android-activity, illegalargumentexception, bottom-sheet

I am facing this issue using a BottomSheet with GoogleMap.

When cicked on any marker, I show the BottomSheet.

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

And I hide it when clicked somewhere on the Map.

```
mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);

        }
    });
```

But as soon as i click on the map, and expect it to hide, my application crashes with the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal state argument: 5
 at android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior.startSettlingAnimation(BottomSheetBehavior.java:629)
 at android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.java:552)
 at app.iwiz.windrock.activities.HomeNavigationActivity$3.onMapClick(HomeNavigationActivity.java:278)
 at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$23.onMapClick(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzq$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
 at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:507)
 at er.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11975448:20)
 at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.ay.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11975448:5)
 at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.af.c(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11975448:212)
 at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.cr.onSingleTapConfirmed(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11975448:28)
 at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.gesture.h.onSingleTapConfirmed(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11975448:124)
 at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.gesture.d.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11975448:26)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

I have discovered that the `state 5` is for the **Hidden Behaviour** of the BottomSheet, But I am not able to understand why is it crashing and how to fix it.

Comment: Did you find the solution to this problem? I get this error event after I moved to material components 1.1.0.

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered the same problem too and I found out that it was because I've set the bottom sheet's hideable bahaviour to false.

> SO, Make sure you add `app:behavior_hideable="true"` attribute to your
>   bottom sheet layout

or if you intend to make your bottom sheet not hideable by user itself and only hideable programmatically, simply call bottomSheetBehaviour.setHideable(true) before you hide it like this:

```
mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0) {
         mBottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(true);
         mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add

```
if(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED){
 mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
}
```

Comment: Well I tried
` if(mBottomSheetBehavior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED){
                    mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
                }`

It didn't work

Comment: Always add explanations to answers. Just as questions needs to be clear, so do answers.